# Body div element will not extend past certain point on the page

Tags: html, css

I ran into this issue while implementing a sticky footer solution. I have the footer working well, but my body element which encompasses everything within the  tag just will not auto-extend beyond a random point further down that can only be reached by scrolling down (it's a lengthy page). My intention is for the body container (does that sound morbid or what?) to auto extend past all the div elements it contains. Isn't that what it's supposed to be doing? Right now there are still div elements sitting further down from where it ends, and the footer is sitting in the middle of my page right below it. If I can't achieve this behavior, I'll have to set the body to a fixed position in css, which I don't want to do.

Using the following CSS styling doesn't work, probably because my content extends beyond a page.

```
html, body {min-height: 100%; height: 100%;}
```

Can someone articulate what the most likely issues could be? Also, feel free to make any constructive comments on my code. This is my first web project.

Here's a link to my HTML code on CodePaste: [HTML Code](https://codepaste.net/fztgjg)

And here's a link to my CSS code: [CSS Code](https://codepaste.net/9sp5bn)

Lastly, a link to a screenshot of my webpage showing the issue. [Screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/o2gQlF5.png/)
The green bar is the footer, and the red border is the body element styled in css so it can be viewed. You'll see it ends right after the picture.

Comment: 100% and a-minimum-of-100% still make 100%, and not more.

Comment: first of all sorry to say your css and html is written very badly ..

Comment: First of all, I asked for constructive comments, which means you have to point out why you think it's badly written. Until then, your comment means nothing to me. It adds nothing to the conversation, and is just a distraction. Very poorly written on your part.

Answer (score 1):

**I'm pretty sure your main problem is setting the height of the body tag.** Try not giving it a height (no `max-height` or `height` tags) or giving it `height: auto` to make it expand as its contents.

**It could also be that you are setting child elements to `positon: absolute`** which means that the parent will collapse to the size of whatever non-absolute elements are inside it.

Also, why the `<p1>` tags? They should be just `<p>`.

#### Code criticism:

It was extremely difficult to figure out what the problem was and I'm not sure that I gave the correct solution because of the way you showed your code. In future, try to give your code as a JSFiddle or a Codepen.

Also, consider using a CSS framework which will reduce the amount of CSS code you write a lot. I would suggest [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) or [Materialize](http://materializecss.com/) but Bootstrap is more widely used.

Don't forget to follow [CSS guidelines](https://google.github.io/styleguide/htmlcssguide.html) which will make your code more readable.

Comment: _pretty sure_ means _guessing_, which is a really bad way to answer a question, so I might down vote later. If you update and it turns out to be correct, notify me and I might even up vote

Comment: Hey Ori, thanks a ton for looking at that and referencing those links. The CSS guidelines were especially useful. You and another commenter suggested changing <p1> to just <p>. That worked to push the <body> div past the <p> element, but not the rest. It gave me an idea though. With no CSS position set, <p> was working correctly. I noticed most of my other elements were set to an absolute position. I eventually got it working by changing the bulk of the content to relative or static positions.

Answer (score 0):

I don't exactly know what the question is asking, but I experimented a bit and figured that if you remove the `1` from the `<p1>` so you would have a normal `<p>` tag, it moves the text up completely. I have a very rough [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/q8801b2c/).

Comment: Hey Sankarsh, I didn't downvote your comment, not sure who did or why. The essence of my question was how to make everything contained in the <body> element push down the <body> to the very bottom of the page, instead of just flowing over it. Your suggestion did help with the <p> element. It made me realize something. I think I need to remove the absolute positioning from all my other elements and use static or relative. I think that should do it. Thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You could stretch the element to the full height of the window using vh.

```
.container{
    height: 100vh;
}
```

You could then position your footer to the bottom using absolute position.

```
footer{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

I've used this in the past for full page landing pages that aren't meant to scroll.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks to all who contributed. Based on suggestions from Sankarsh and Ori, I was able to solve the problem. Once I changed my  div to just

as they suggested, I noticed it began functioning as I intended and forcing the parent  element down beneath it. Unfortunately, that only solved the problem for that element alone. That led to me discovering the

element had a default "static" position, while most of my other elements were set to "absolute". After changing the positions of the bulk of my content to "relative" or "static", everything is working as intended!

**TLDR:** If you want a child element to stay within the boundaries of its parent element, you need to set the child's position to "static" or "relative". You cannot use "absolute". This way, instead of overflowing beyond the border of the parent, the child will automatically extend the parent's border to its intended position.